# Amazon Athena parsing JSON

Tags: json, presto, amazon-athena

Struggling to parse some json.
This is the format, where there are no fixed names/keys - everything is dynamic.

```
{ "{condition-operator}" : { "{condition-key}" : "{condition-value}" }}
```

An an example of values:

```
{
  "bool":{"aws:viaawsservice":"true"},
  "stringequals":{
        "ec2:createaction":[
            "CreateSecurityGroup",
            "CreateVolume",
            "CreateSnapshot",
            "RunInstances"
        ]
    }
}
```

I've managed to extract the 'operator' and 'key' values. (See below)

However, my result for 'values' is problematic.

One value is 'true',
the other ["CreateSecurityGroup","CreateVolume","CreateSnapshot","RunInstances"]

Neither of which I seem able to use or cast as an UNNESTable array.

To be honest, getting woefully lost in what's going on !!
I need to be able to unnest these, to get 1 row per value (so 5 values/rows in total)

Any guidance appreciated !

```
with cte as (
  select '{"bool":{"aws:viaawsservice":"true"},"stringequals":{"ec2:createaction":["CreateSecurityGroup","CreateVolume","CreateSnapshot","RunInstances"]}}'
    as sample
)
select 
  ,ct.ct as condition_operator
  ,map_keys(cast(ct.cb as map<varchar,json>))[1] as condition_key
  , map_values(cast(ct.cb as map<varchar,json>))[1] as condition_values
from 
  cte
  CROSS JOIN UNNEST(map_keys(cast(json_parse(cte.sample)as map<varchar,json>)),map_values(cast(json_parse(cte.sample)as map<varchar,json>))) ct(ct,cb)
  -- CROSS JOIN UNNEST( ## something here ##) as values(v)



condition_ope..   condition_key       condition_values 
(string(255))    (string(255))       (json) 
bool             aws:viaawsservice   "true" 
stringequals     ec2:createaction ["CreateSecurityGroup","CreateVolume","CreateSnapshot","RunInstances"]
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`try`](https://prestodb.io/docs/current/functions/conditional.html?highlight=try#try), which results in `null` in case of failure, and attempt to cast data to `array` of `varchar` and fallback to either cast to `varchar` (which will fail in case of json object in value) or just using `json_format`:

```sql
select ct.ct as condition_operator,
    ct_key,
    ct_value
from cte
    CROSS JOIN UNNEST(
        map_keys(cast(json_parse(cte.sample) as map < varchar, json >)),
        map_values(cast(json_parse(cte.sample) as map < varchar, json >))
    ) ct(ct, cb)
    CROSS JOIN UNNEST(
        map_keys(cast(ct.cb as map < varchar, json >)),
        map_values(cast(ct.cb as map < varchar, json >))
    ) ct1(ct_key, ct_value_json)
    CROSS JOIN UNNEST(
        coalesce(try(cast(ct_value_json as array < varchar >)),array [ json_format(ct_value_json) ]
        )
    ) ct2(ct_value)
```

Output:

| condition_operator | ct_key | ct_value |
| --- | --- | --- |
| bool | aws:viaawsservice | true |
| stringequals | ec2:createaction | CreateSecurityGroup |
| stringequals | ec2:createaction | CreateVolume |
| stringequals | ec2:createaction | CreateSnapshot |
| stringequals | ec2:createaction | RunInstances |